# Can I write swift on Windows?

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering if I can write iOS applications on windows using [runswiftlang.com](http://www.runswiftlang.com/). This website enables me to write Swift apps and run the apps on it. Can I write code like the following on the website and save it to a .swift file?

```
func anyMultipleOf(value: Int, numbers: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return numbers.reduce(false) {
        any, number in
        return any || ((value % number) == 0)
    }
}

let sum = [Int](1..<1000).filter() { anyMultipleOf($0, [3, 5]) }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
println(sum)
```

If not I want to know what programming languages enable me to develop iOS apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need a Mac machine to build (native or hybrid) iOS apps. Aside from Objective C or Swift, there are a couple of other options (mostly multi-platform solutions that target Android and/or Windows Phone as well), like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com) (based on C#), [PhoneGap/Cordova](http://phonegap.com) (based on HTML/JavaScript) and [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com) (based on HTML/Javascript).

Answer (score 3):

Swift is apple only and so is Objective-C however there are a few tools that let you make Mobile Apps on windows I still think that the actual creation of the application package for iOS has to happen on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

Swift language is used for *developing iOS/Mac apps*. You can *write small programs and execute it using online tools* (such as http://www.runswiftlang.com/ as mentioned by you) but in order to create apps its mandatory to have a MacBook/Mac Mini/iMac. Since apps can only be developed in **Xcode (IDE) using Swift/Objective-C** language.

Also, in order to *test your app you need simulator* which is embedded with Xcode only. If you want to put an app on the App Store then you need to test app on real device (iPad or iPhone).

**Conclusion :** *You can write small programs on Windows system using online tools* but in order to develop full-fledged app you need to have the following:

> 1. Apple developer account (Paid account)
> 2. Workstation for writing code (MacBook/iMac/Mac mini etc)
> 3. Apple device for testing app (iPhone/iPad etc)

Comment: i did not agree with you, you do not need Paid Apple Developer Program, you can use unpaid version for test on real device. But it's account restricted only one real device.

Comment: @EmreGürses : This has been changed since iOS 10. Earlier it was mandatory to have Paid Apple Developer program.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, yes!

There’s a swift toolchain and runtime for compiling Swift and running natively on Windows. At this point it is mature enough to provide all the expected types from standard, plus the core libraries including Foundation, dispatch, and XCTest. REPL works too.

Get the Windows toolchain and get started here: https://www.swift.org/getting-started/

There’s also some community driven efforts to extend Swift’s obj-C interoperability to a more generic C++ interface.